# Laravel Join query is not working for 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel

I have 4 tables

Table Name : Clinics

Fields: clinicID , clinicName

Table Name : locations

Fileds: locationID, clinicID,locationname

Table Name : Services

Fields: ServiceId , ServiceName

Table Name: LocationServices

Fields: locationServiceID, locationID , ServiceId

My requiremnt is that when i pass clinicID, i need to retrive Corresponding clinics  service name, there may be more than one.

But when i tried join query is not working 
Following is my code in controller

```
 public function showClinic($id)
    {
        $clinic = Clinic::find($id);
        $locations = Location::where('clinicID', $id)->get();
        $locationsservices=\App\Clinic::with('locations');
        var_dump($locationsservices);
        die();
        return view('clinic.show')->with(['locations' =>  $locations  ,'clinic'=>$clinic]);

    }
```

Comment: Please share your models with us. How did you define relationships between entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this details by using relationships.
In the `Clinic` model,add

```
public function locations()
 {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Locations','clinicID','clinicID');
 }
```

In the `Locations` model,add,

```
 public function location_services()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\LocationServices','locationID','locationID');
 }
```

On the `LocationServices` model,

```
 public function services()
 {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Services','ServiceId','ServiceId');
 }
```

You can get the result by,

```
$clinic_info = Clinic::find($id);
if(isset($clinic_info->locations))
{
  if(isset($clinic_info->locations->location_services))
  {
    if(isset($clinic_info->locations->location_services->services))
    {
      echo $clinic_info->locations->location_services->services->ServiceName;
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Reference Maybe HelpFull for You

***Multi Joins***

```
$data = DB::table('city')
       ->join('state', 'state.state_id', '=', 'city.state_id')
       ->join('country', 'country.country_id', '=', 'state.country_id')
       ->select('country.country_name', 'state.state_name', 'city.city_name')
       ->get();
     return view('join_table', compact('data'));
```